# How to use HTML5 picture element in Bootstrap-Vue Carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue

From [Bootstrap Vue Carousel Documenation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/carousel)

its not clear how to use HTML5 picture element like so:

```
<picture>
      <source srcset="img/awesomeWebPImage.webp" type="image/webp">
      <source srcset="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
      <img src="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" alt="Alt Text!">
    </picture>
```

It mentions below code for img slot:

```
<!-- Slides with img slot -->
      <!-- Note the classes .d-block and .img-fluid to prevent browser default image alignment -->
      <b-carousel-slide>
        <img
          slot="img"
          class="d-block img-fluid w-100"
          width="1024"
          height="480"
          src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=55"
          alt="image slot"
        >
      </b-carousel-slide>
```

I need to support webp for those browsers that can handle webp or use JPEG for those browsers not supporting webp.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The picture element replaces the image element like so:

```html
<!-- Slides with img slot -->
<!-- Note the classes .d-block and .img-fluid to prevent browser default image alignment -->
<b-carousel-slide>
  <picture>
    <source srcset="img/awesomeWebPImage.webp" type="image/webp">
    <img src="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" alt="Alt Text!" slot="img" class="d-block img-fluid w-100" width="1024" height="480">
  </picture>
</b-carousel-slide>
```

The way picture should be used is determine which image to use based on what fits best. In your case which file types are supported. The attributes with the image are applied to the final image.